# How to show double orthogonal complement $X$ is a subset of closure of $X$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that $\bar{X} = (X^{\perp })^{\perp } $. I have already shown $\bar{X} \subset  (X^{\perp })^{\perp }$ but how to show the reverse inclusion? I don't really have any idea where to start. I was thinking maybe if we suppose $x \notin \bar{X} $ then there is some $\epsilon >0 $ such that for any $u \in X$ we have $||x-u ||\geq \epsilon $. But can't really get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $X$ is Banach. Suppose that $x$ is not in $\bar X$, Hahn-Banach implies the existence of a linear continuous function $f$ such that $f(x)=1, f(y)=0$ if $y\in \bar X$. $f$ is in $X^{\perp}$. This implies that $x$ is not an element of $(X^{\perp})^{\perp}$.